# PHP Directory listing not working

Tags: php

PHP Directory listing is not working, what am I doing wrong?. There are folders in the movies directory, but they are not showing in my output.

```
<?php       
    // declare the folder    
    $ourDir = "movies";

    // prepare to read directory contents    
    $ourDirList = @opendir($ourDir);

    // loop through the items    
    while ($ourItem = readdir($ourDirList))    
    {        
       // check if it is a directory    
       if (is_dir($ourItem))    
       {    
          echo $ourItem;   
          echo "<br />";   
       }
    }
closedir($ourDirList);
?>
```

Comment: after `<?php` add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` and remove `@` from `opendir` and then check by running your script again

Comment: I tried your suggestion. I get no errors, and still no directory listing. The movie folder is in the same directory as the php script (there are also 2 empty folders inside the movie folder).

Comment: check you `movies` folder permission(need to be 077)

Comment: was not permissions. I got it working with this

was not permissions. I got it working with this

    <?php
    
    $dir = "movies";
    $exclude = array( ".","..",".*","*.php" );
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        $files = scandir($dir);
        foreach($files as $file){
            if(!in_array($file,$exclude)){
                echo '<li><a href=' . $dir . '/' . $file . '>' . $file . '</a></li>';

            }
        }
    }

    ?>

Answer (score 1):

issue is when you are checking if $ourItem is a folder, you are forgetting is looking in the current directory for the folder.

see below.

```
// declare the folder    
$ourDir = "movies";

// prepare to read directory contents    
$ourDirList = @opendir($ourDir);

// loop through the items    
while ($ourItem = readdir($ourDirList))    
{        
   // check if it is a directory 
   if (is_dir($ourDir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$ourItem) )    
   {    
      echo $ourItem;   
      echo "<br />";   
   }
}closedir($ourDirList);
```